# SQL SELECT depending on multiple variables and tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, select

I'm trying to create a `SELECT` query, but the problem here is that I get multiple variables that suitable for different table.

To make it clear I'll present the database tables :

**Category**

```
   CatID
   CatName
```

**Subcategory**

```
   CatID
   SubCatID
   SubCatName
```

**Company**

```
    CompanyID
    CompName
    SubCat
```

**Model**

```
   CompID
   ModelID
   ModelName
```

**Posts**

```
   PostID
   ModelID
```

Now, I get some parameters like : Cat, Subcat, Category, ModelID and Name, and what i need is to select all the matching results of PostID that suits for the parameters.

E.g, if I get the following parameters :

```
Cat = "Electronics"
Subcat="Computers"
Company="Apple"
ModelName="Macbook Air"
Keyword="new"
```

I need to get the following results of **Posts** where the category equals to the Cat variables, and the subcategory matches the SubCat Variable and so on.. and in addition to filter the result using `%Like%` for the keyword variable that I got.

Unfortunately I failed after a lot of tries trying to solve it. Tried using the Inner JOIN in different ways, but it didn't work.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this, because I got not idea how to continue form this point, and I don't have a lot of time till I need to finish this project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't a category just a subcategory without a parent?  Do you need two tables?  Regardless, I would write one query at a time and show us what you have so far so we can help you find the issue

Comment: Well, It is, but I do need two tables for another use in the website.. I had multiple attempts leading to no solution or a way so it is useless to post it.. Although, I just noticed someone answered this question, So i will give it a try and tell you if it has worked.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select posts.*
from Posts inner join
    model on posts.modelId = model.modelId and model.ModelName = 'Macbook Air' inner join
    Company on model.compID = company.companyID and Company.CompName = 'Apple' inner join
    Subcategory on company.subCat = Subcategory.SubcatID and subcategory.subcatName ='Computers' inner join
    Category on subcategory.catID = category.catID and category.CatName = 'Electronics'
where posts.keywordField like '%new%'
```

I had to make some assumptions there, like what field you are trying to search for your keyword in. But you get the general idea: at each inner join you can specify an additional condition that will limit your results, and in this manner apply your parameters to your query.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Worked Perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to make this work would be to create a View so you only have one table to search against.

```
Select c.*, sc.SubCatName, com.*, ModelName, p.*
from Category c 
join Subcategory sc on c.CatID = sc.CatID
join Company com on sc.SubCatID = com.SubCatID
join Model m on com.CompID = com.CompID
join Posts p on p.ModelID = m.ModelID
```

Comment: Thank you for your response ! I'm trying to embed this in my project but I'm having some troubles to understand what is the "p" variable that appears in your answers, Because we only get the cat (c), subcat (sc), company (com) and model(m). Thanks

Comment: @SIOS_dev you had a 'Posts' table and I aliased it to 'p'